# Get first day of the set year

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```sql
declare @coyear varchar (max) 
set @coyear = '2018'
SELECT (YEAR(DATEADD(year,0,@coyear)))
```

I have set `@coyear` as 2018 and I am getting 2018 in result.
I want first day of the year which I have set for year.
For example when I pass 2018 in `@coyear` I want 2018-01-01 in result.

Comment: `DATEFROMPARTS()` ?

Comment: Completely changing the question after receiving answers, and invalidating them, is severely frowned upon, @Anuragsharma , please don't do it. [Ask a **new** question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) as it seems you have a different question to what you are expressing in the comments under my answer.

Comment: `declare @coyear varchar (max)` THINK about your code! Why is this declared as string? And why a string of 2billion characters? Learning bad habits is a terrible way to start.

Answer (score 1):

`DATEFROMPARTS` would seem a better solution:

```
DECLARE @CoYear int; --Why would you need 2GB/2 Billion characters for a year?
SET @CoYear = 2018;
SELECT DATEFROMPARTS(@CoYear, 1, 1);
```

Comment: Thanks Larnu . Yeah that was by mistake .

Comment: If I want to get last day for example 2018-12-31 . I tried SELECT DATEFROMPARTS(@CoYear, +1, -1); but did not help . Thanks in advance

Comment: Use `EOMONTH` to get the last day of the month, @Anuragsharma .

Comment: Also, `-1` as a parameter for `DATEFROMPARTS` makes no sense. Have a look at it's [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datefromparts-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) if you don't understand what it does.

Comment: @Larne If i want last day for any month for any year . I tried this declare comonth int ='12' declare coyear int ='2018' SELECT EOMONTH(comonth, coyear) . but it did not help .Thanks in advance

Comment: ... @Anuragsharma really you should be asking a new question if you want to know how to get the last day of a year as well, or *at least* edit your question.

Comment: Though getting the last day of the year is just as trivial as the above without `EOMONTH` too, @Anuragsharma . Hint: December is the 12th month and has 31 days.

Comment: I did not understand your point . I have edited the original question .

Comment: @Larna i have to manually enter the date as for october , 31 or for november ,30 to get the last date . I just want to enter the month and year and it should return the last date of the entered month

Comment: Then, again, look at `EOMONTH`, *or* ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

By Using DATEFROMPARTS

```
DECLARE @Year INT = 2021;

SELECT DATEFROMPARTS(@Year, 1, 1) AS Result;
```

Answer (score 0):

All versions. Try this:

```
DECLARE @Year int = 2018
SELECT CONVERT(date, LTRIM(@Year))
```