# Get last day of any month for any year

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```sql
declare @comonth int ='10'
declare @coyear int ='2018'

SELECT EOMONTH(@CoYear, @comonth)
```

I have set `@coyear` as 2018 and `@comonth` as 10. I want result as 2018-10-31. (last date of the month). What statement do I have to use?

Comment: If you have a look at `EOMONTH`'s documentation, you'll see the first parameter expected is a date and time data type. The second is optional and adds that many months to the date.

Answer (score 4):

This is the same principle as your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67883694/get-first-day-of-the-set-year), and why I suggested you read the documentation on [`DATEFROMPARTS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datefromparts-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and [`EOMONTH`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/eomonth-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) as it explains how to use both functions:

```sql
DECLARE @comonth int = 10; --Don't wrap numerical values in single quotes(')
DECLARE @coyear int = 2018; --Don't wrap numerical values in single quotes(')

SELECT EOMONTH(DATEFROMPARTS(@coyear,@comonth,1)); --All months's have a day 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Good for all versions. Try this:

```
DECLARE @Year   int         = 2030
    ,   @Month  int         = 10
;   
DECLARE @Date   datetime    = CONVERT(datetime, LTRIM(@Year*10000+@Month*100+1))
;
SELECT DATEADD(mm, 0, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, @Date) + 1, 0))-1
```